# Angular JS Using ng-repeat and ng-click with external function

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular page which involves table creation using ng-repeat directive. I want to make each row of the table clickable and the event must trigger a function that is supplied in the data set.

Here is my table row

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in data_list"  ng-click="{{ i.row_onclick }}">
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ i.thingID }}" />
        {{ i.date | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

The `i.row_click` property is a whole function call, of the form

```
ShowFrame('View', 'RGF0ZVJhbmdlVHlwZT1jdXN0b20jI1N0YXJ0RGF0ZT0xMS8xLzI')
```

and differs for each row.

The `ShowFrame` is not a `$scope` attribute, and is an external function.

I tried replacing the `ng-click` with `onclick`, which resulted in an error saying `i is not defined`

How can I tackle this?

Comment: if i.row_onclick is a function maybe you'r missing the parenthesis ? i.row_onclick() ?

Comment: the content of i.row_click is as shown in the question

Comment: Is `i.row_click` a string or a real reference to the function you described?

Comment: its a string as shown in the question

Comment: Then you either have to parse and link it to a *real* function yourself or use some kind of `eval`. There's no angular magic which could help you.

Answer (score 0):

with **ng-click** you dont need double braces

change

```
ng-click="{{ i.row_onclick }}"
```

to

```
ng-click="i.row_onclick()"
```

and in your controllers make sure you type

```
$scope.i.row_onclick = function () {   
    // your handler 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) uses expression evaluation syntax, ie`ng-click="i.row_onclick()"`